# Custom PTZ camera controll from Appindicator

Tags: python

**EDIT 1**

- Changed code to PEP8

My task is to create custom script to control PTZ (pan-tilt-zoom) cameras. We have an application for video surveillance but problem is that some functions are missing, like speed zoom out. Also, some cameras loses focus etc.

My idea is to create appindicator to control cameras from there. Below is python script, and it's working, so my question here is, can I change this code a bit for a better performance or to improve something? I am not so familiar with python, so this is more like a test project for now. I am using API to control cameras from script.

***file: lib/Camctrl.py***

```
import urllib


class Camctrl(object):
"""
Base class for Cam control
"""

def __init__(self, ip, param):
    self.ip = ip  # last part of IP address
    self.param = param
    self.getUrl().zoomOut()  # execute

def getUrl(self):
    self.url = "http://user:pass@192.168.188.{0}/cgi-bin/camctrl/camctrl.cgi?".format(
        self.ip)
    return self

def zoomOut(self):

    if type(self.param).__name__ != 'list':   # Execute one operation
        url = self.url+self.param
        self.execurl(url)

    else:  # execute multiple, iterate through list

        for command in self.param:
            command = str(command)
            url = self.url+command
            self.execurl(url)

def execurl(self, url):
    try:
        urllib.urlopen(url)
    except:
        pass
```

Camctrl have a task to execute command. It accepts last part of IP address, as well as params (one command is string, multiple are list).

***file: lib/Gui.py***

```
import appindicator
import gtk
from Camctrl import Camctrl


class Gui(object):

    def __init__(self, menuList, icon="None"):

        self.icon = icon
        self.statusMenu = gtk.Menu()
        self.menuList = menuList
        self.menuItemsNumber = len(menuList)
        self.getInstance().createMenus().packMenu()   # Start program

    def getInstance(self):
        """
        Create appindicator
        """

        self.appIndicator = appindicator.Indicator(
            'wallch_indicator',
            self.icon,
            appindicator.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
        self.appIndicator.set_status(appindicator.STATUS_ACTIVE)
        return self

    def createMenus(self):
        """
        Create menu items from the given list
        Args:
            menuList (List) = List of cameras    ***
            [0] - Name of camera (appears in menu),
            [1] - last part of ip address

        """

        for key, val in enumerate(self.menuList):
            item = gtk.MenuItem(val[0])
            self.menuList[key][0] = item

        return self

    def signals(self, item, val):
        params = [
            "setzoom=0",
            "zoom=tele&speedzoom=2",
            "zoom=wide&speedzoom=2"]
        normal = "setzoom=0"

        if val is '140':
            Camctrl('140', params)
        else:
            Camctrl(val, normal)

    def packMenu(self):
        for val in self.menuList:
            self.statusMenu.append(val[0])
            val[0].show()
            val[0].connect('activate', self.signals, val[1])

        self.appIndicator.set_menu(self.statusMenu)

        gtk.main()
```

File Gui.py have a task to create appindicator and menus. Inside `signals` function are two different lists, because one camera have issues with auto-focus, so it must zoom out, then zoom in a bit and zoom out again, and then focus is correct.

Main scrip, to run everything is `main.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from lib.Gui import Gui
from lib.Camctrl import Camctrl

cameras = [
    ['Rotaciona el.kasa', '140'],
    ['Rotaciona konfekcija', '79'],
    ['Rotaciona VIP', '47'],
    ['Rotaciona mesara', '107'],
    ['Zadnja rotaciona', '13'],
    ['Rotaciona ispred', '159']
]

Gui(cameras, "/usr/share/icons/cctv.png")  # cameras and custom icon
```

In order to start script, you must have `python-appindicator`.